# Bulk load Insert in Elasticsearch with large volume

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 10GB data, that i need to load into elastic-search index, and I have converted the data to JSON formatted.
My question is when i try to load all the data into elastic search using CRUL command its thrown below error.
at the same time when I split the JSON files to multiple 1GB files then it works fine.
Do we need to follow any methodology to load large size file to elasticsearch or any predefined tools are available ? Please advise here !

Full File(10GB)

```
curl -XPOST 'http://servername:9200/xyz/tmp/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @/home/xyz/test.json
```

Error

```
curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

Split File(Success command)

```
curl -XPOST 'http://servername:9200/xyz/tmp/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @/home/xyz/test_split1.json
curl -XPOST 'http://servername:9200/xyz/tmp/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @/home/xyz/test_split2.json
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a http request size limit of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `2^31-1` which is basically **2GB**.

If you check your ES logs you would see something like this `HTTP content length exceeded 104857600 bytes` and hence you can not index 10GB data at once, you have to split the file.

Please refer to [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html). Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841221/what-is-the-maximum-elasticsearch-document-size) would help a lot