# elasticsearch - count items after post

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch client for node js (working with elastic 2.x), and I want to avoid the exception that is thrown when the maximum number of documents allowed per index is exceeded. I could not find the name of the exception anywhere, so if possible, I would like to get the number of documents in the index at the same query where I POST data to db. Otherwise I will need to run a separate count query before or after each POST. Any type of solution will be appreciated.

Comment: can you post your exception and this might help. Size of indices are not limited. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841221/what-is-the-maximum-elasticsearch-document-size. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-maximum-size-an-index-can-store-in-Elasticsearch-What-is-the-maximum-size-of-the-document

Comment: I didn't get this exception, I just want to avoid it