# Uploading large GEOJson to elastic

Tags: json, elasticsearch, curl, upload, geojson

I'm having some trouble uploading a GEOJson to my local elastic server.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/geo/_doc' -d @earth-lands-1m.geo.json
```

The file is a `GeometryCollection` with a lot of objects:

```
{"type":"GeometryCollection", "geometries": [ <polygon objects>] }
```

The file is 140M and this doesn't give any output, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files so large are more or less guaranteed to fail. I'd recommend

- [splitting the geojson](https://medium.com/@underchemist/splitting-geojson-files-using-geojsplit-8ff72ec68c67) features first
- and using [bulk sync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61642184/8160318) (python) or [`json-to-es-bulk`](https://github.com/mradamlacey/json-to-es-bulk) (nodejs + curl) to split the payloads even further.
- On top of that, have a look at [tuning for indexing speed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html) if you're still unsatisfied w/ the ... indexing speed.

Comment: It seems that splitting a GeometryCollection isn't possible with the suggested library in the first link

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: The suggested library - https://github.com/woodb/geojsplit - doesn't work with a GeometryCollection which is the type I mentioned in the question. According to the elastic documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html, this is just a collection of polygons. So I'm wondering if I can just split it to separate objects and upload each - but not 100% sure

Comment: Yes, splitting is the way to go. You need (multi)polygons only, you don't really care about the collection itself. Unless you have some top-level props you wanna preserve. In that case you just include them in each individual document at sync/ingest time.

Comment: Nope, no top level props. Cool, so I can just take each member of the geometries array and bulk send the thing assuming each of them isn't too big.

Comment: @1 Yes. @2 although ES supports MultiPolygons too, I think they're internally represented as singular polygons. Reindexing & searching is going to be faster if the docs are smaller so splitting the large multipolygons is the way to go.

Comment: What would be the downside of uploading three 50mb multipolygons? The purpose of the DB is to query if the multipolygons contain a given polygon

Comment: 50MB is fine since the limit is ~100MB. More at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62046953/8160318

Comment: @Valu3 how did you manage to upload large GeoJson to ElasticSearch? 
Did you index the whole GeometryCollection object? (if so, can you somehow bulk index it?) Or you split GeometryCollection into multiple Geometry objects and bulk indexed them? If so, did you find any limitations (data, performance, etc.)? Thank you!

Comment: @JoeSorocin What are the differences and pro / cons of ingesting ElasticSearch geoshape as multiple individual Geometry objects (polygons in individual documents) rather than one single GeometryCollection (polygons in a single document)?
What about indexing (execution time and performance - even when using Bulk Index)?
What about querying, searching, filtering (usability, performance, etc.)? Thank you!